# Cant search for things in the start menu Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, bug

If I try to search for stuff using the start menu, nothing happens. The mouse will flicker with the spinner. If I turn on the search box, typing in it will cause it to immediately reject what I typed and go unfocused.

I got this error when I started my computer:
[Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbqUP.png) I tried to go to the path it specified, but was rejected for not having permissions. I tried to run the app with command prompt and got this error: [Access is denied.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQq3J.png)
At one point yesterday it started working again, but after a restart, it has stopped once more.

I just did a repair to try and fix this, which fixed another issue I was having but left the start menu unchanged.

Comment: A repair has at least cleaned up some things.  Try the following:  Make a new, test, Windows User Account (Profile). Go to Start, Settings, Accounts to do this. Log in as the new Windows User and see if the Start Menu works for the new User.

Comment: My computer is not looking to good. Clicking Add someone else to this PC causes the window for creating the account to pop up, but it immediately closes in the same way that the settings menu was before.

Comment: Alright, I used command promt to create the account, and start seems to work there. I did have to restart my computer when switching accounts though, which is not a good sign

Comment: If your new account is working, that is how to proceed. As I noted in the other thread, if things are very badly messed up, you may wish to back everything up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's non-reproducible because the problem was solved by reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled windows and everything is working now.